# vue3 computed getters and setters for radio buttons

Tags: vuex, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-script-setup

I am trying to update my vuex store based on a radio input using vue3 computed getters and setters. I have it working for simple text inputs but for the radio buttons and checkboxes it is seeming to be a little trickier.
I have looked at a few tutorials online and I'm not too sure what I'm getting wrong. I had it working in vue2 but it was mutating the props but my vue3 setup gives a warning saying the props are read only.

```
<template>
    <div v-for="(option, id) in propData.options" v-bind:key="id">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" v-model='radio' />
            <span v-text="option.text" />
        </label>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>

    import { defineProps, toRefs, defineEmits, computed } from 'vue';
    import { useStore } from 'vuex';

    const store = useStore();

    const props = defineProps({
        propData: Object,
    });

    const { propData } = toRefs(props);

    const emit = defineEmits(['update:propData'])

    const radio = computed({
        get () {
            return propData
        },
        set(val) {
            emit('update:propData', val);
        }
    })
</script>
```

this is propData:

```
    [
        {
            "value": "yes",
            "text": "answer 1",
            "selected": true,
        },
        {
            "value": "no",
            "text": "answer 2",
            "selected": false,
        },
        {
            "text": "Other",
            "value": "answer 3",
            "selected": false,
        }
    ]
```

the idea is to have selected updated to false for all radio buttons and for the radio button clicked on to be true. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the wrong path. Keep the list of allowed options and the list of currently selected ones separately. Otherwise everytime you update the list of options with the new selected flag - it will rerender each of the `v-for` items.

```html
<template>
    <div v-for="(option, id) in options" :key="id">
        <label>
            <input v-model="selected" type="radio" :value="option.value" />
            <span v-text="option.text" />
        </label>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters, mapMutations } from 'vuex';

export default
{
  props:
  {
    options:
    {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    },
  },
  computed:
  {
    ...mapGetters(['getSelectedOptions']),
    selected:
    {
      get()
      {
        return this.getSelectedOptions || [];
      },
      set(val)
      {
        this.setSelectedOptions(val);
      }
    }
  },
  methods:
  {
    ...mapMutations(['setSelectedOptions']),
  }
</script>
```